# Reducing image resolution in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to reduce the image resolution while maintaining the original width and height?

I have tried several options using BitmapFactoryOptions:

1. inSampleSize
2. inDensity, inScaled, inTargetDensity

Both ways reduce the image width and height. But what I want is to just reducing the image resolution without affecting the image width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of "resolution" is "width and height". Hence, you cannot change the resolution without changing the width and height.

---

> The image is captured from android device camera. I use the BitmapFactory to resize the image upon onActivityResult.

Whether or not you can do anything to reduce the file size further depends a lot on what the camera application does, and there are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of camera applications.

You are welcome to experiment with:

- Saving the JPEG at lower quality when you write it out, [using `compress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream))
- Reducing the bit depth when you read it in, [using `inPreferredConfig`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig) and RGB_565
- Finding other JPEG optimization algorithms and trying to get them working on Android, possibly involving the NDK

Comment: How does facebook android app able reduce the image size while maintaining the width and height? Or, how should I reduce the image size without affecting the width and height?

Comment: @user970307: What do you mean by "image size"? The number of bytes on disk? The number of bytes of heap space? The apparent visual size to the user? The length of the filename of the image file? Unless you explain **precisely** what you mean by "image size", it will be very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: The image size is the file size of that image.

Comment: @user970307: OK! Now we are getting somewhere! Next: what sort of image is this, and where is this image coming from? You said that you were using `BitmapFactory`, and that is used to convert an existing PNG or JPEG image into a `Bitmap`. Is your image a PNG? A JPEG? Something else? Is the image already on disk, or are you downloading it? What file type are you trying to save the image as?

Comment: The image is captured from android device camera. I use the BitmapFactory to resize the image upon onActivityResult. The image originally saved as .jpeg in the device. Once I post the image to my server, I saved it as .png.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are unclear with the very definition of resolution.

perhaps you want to reduce the resolution of the image (width and height) and then show it in an ImageView of greater size .

For that you should simply set the reduced resolution image as the source of any greater size ImageView with Scaling (ScaleType) set to Stretch